# How to implement swipe on tabbedpage in Xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel, xamarin-studio, tabbed

I am new to Xamarin.Form. I want to implement swipe on tabbedPage. I searched a lot, but I could find the exact solution. Please if anyone having any idea let me know.

Comment: Tabbed page on Android already supports swipes. On iOS I'm not using them as they are just looking ugly.

Comment: how to enable that ?

Comment: But i am using Xamarin.Form

Comment: Me too, im using xamarin forms. When i swipe on Android tabs are changing, i didnt do anything special..

Comment: Oh yeah thank you sir. its working. actually i was not swiping before . thanks for precious time

Comment: how to make it work on Xamarin forms for iOS case?